# nyc Regular Expression Denial of Service vulnerability while running the npm test

Tags: javascript, node.js, package, mocha.js, nyc

I am new to nodejs, How to fix the `nyc` Regular Expression Denial of Service vulnerability? npm audit is giving this vulnerability while running the npm test.

```
Moderate: Regular Expression Denial of Service  
Package: browserslist
Dependency of: nyc [dev]  
Path: nyc > istanbul-lib-instrument > @babel/core > @babel/helper-compilation-targets > browserslist
```

In my package.json I have nyc dev dependency:

```
"nyc": "^15.1.0"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I cleared the cache and then run `npm install` it worked.